# Fetch: How to download files?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to use the [Fetch Library](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch) for my android app to download files from server.

I am using below code which is copied from the fetch github example :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Fetch fetch;
    Request request;
    Button download;
    String url = "https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
    String file = "/Download/image.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        download = findViewById(R.id.button);
        download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FetchConfiguration fetchConfiguration = new FetchConfiguration.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setDownloadConcurrentLimit(3)
                        .build();
                fetch= Fetch.Impl.getInstance(fetchConfiguration);
                request = new Request(url,file);
                request.setPriority(Priority.HIGH);
                request.setNetworkType(NetworkType.ALL);
                fetch.enqueue(request,updatedRequest -> {
                    //something
                },error -> {
                    //somethig
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but when i click on the download button, this is the error the logcat showed me:

```
    09-17 14:07:36.522 27133-27133/rahul.gaur.test1 E/Process: android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid pid is 27133
    android_os_Process_getProcessNameByPid value is ahul.gaur.test1
09-17 14:07:43.012 27133-27365/rahul.gaur.test1 E/LibGlobalFetchLib: FileDownloader download:DownloadInfo(id=1284541380, 

namespace='LibGlobalFetchLib', url='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 

file='/Download/image.png', group=0, priority=HIGH, headers={}, downloaded=0, total=5969, status=QUEUED, 

error=NONE, networkType=ALL, created=1537173461169, tag=null, enqueueAction=REPLACE_EXISTING, identifier=0, 

downloadOnEnqueue=true, extras={})
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Download/image.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117)
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.SequentialFileDownloaderImpl$run$1.<init>(SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.kt:92)
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.run(SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.kt:90)
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.DownloadManagerImpl$start$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.run

(DownloadManagerImpl.kt:97)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:117) 
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.SequentialFileDownloaderImpl$run$1.<init>(SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.kt:92) 
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.run(SequentialFileDownloaderImpl.kt:90) 
        at com.tonyodev.fetch2.downloader.DownloadManagerImpl$start$$inlined$synchronized$lambda$1.run

(DownloadManagerImpl.kt:97) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1115) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:590) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

my Graddle File :    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "rahul.gaur.test1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName 'Alpha'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
    compileOptions {
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:2.2.0-RC12'
    //implementation 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

i can't download the image. help me to figurout how to use this easily.

Thanx in advance for any help.

Comment: Check your file location or directory is exist or not. Because logcat  shows " java.io.FileNotFoundException: /downloads/fetchdata/file.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

Comment: also check if the permissions are granted

Comment: @MohammodHossain and Farabi Permission is granted and i am downloading the file from the link/server then how it could be in the device ? i seriously didn't get this one. what the file string is used for ? the download location or the server location ?

Comment: @wiils, at first you need to check folder is exists or not . If not create such directory

Comment: @MohammodHossain the Downloads folder does exists on the system by default and it is there i Ch eked, and even i used only file string as "/Downloads/" but then it says open file failed read only system ? damm i really confused with this one.

Comment: @MohammodHossain i've updated the file string in the main question. Please see how to get workaround this. I am really confused to work with this.

Comment: ok. Create a folder named "downloads" and put a image named image.png  then try

Comment: @MohammodHossain fetch is not downloading the file from server then how can i put the image in the location first(dumb from my side maybe) and wth it is trying to open the file from the device instead of downloading and saving it to the location ? and now i am using the `Download` folder which always exists in the system.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally i found the answer this is pretty wick. but this is what it is :

now the file string i was using is : `/Download/image.png`

which was causing the error

now i am using the string as : `EEnvironment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/fetch/image.png";`

it is working as it should.

Sorry for the dumb trouble and thank for trying to help me @Mohammod

Comment: It's my pleasure.  give your vote  if  it solves your probelm

Answer (score 0):

String file = "/Download/image.png";

Use  instead of above code

String file = "/downloads/image.png";

**or use as sample**

String url = "http:www.example.com/test.txt";

String file = "/downloads/test.txt";

in build.gradle

**try it**

implementation "com.tonyodev.fetch2okhttp:fetch2okhttp:2.2.0-RC12"

**instead of**

implementation 'com.tonyodev.fetch2:fetch2:2.2.0-RC12'

Comment: Could you share your build.gradle file.

Comment: Updated it in the main question

Comment: Damm man now the code can't find any of the classes. and btw okhttp is downloader for fetch though so where is fetch now in the app ?